# How to put text in a player's chat box in Minecraft 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to send a message to chat (i.e. 'Click Me') that, when clicked, forces a command into the player's chat box. I assume this is done using the tellraw command, but I cannot quite figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way to tell certain people certain things with clickevents and stuff like that is going to this website: minecraftjson.com . sadly, you cannot force a command into a chat box(the box you type in after you press 't' to send a public message throughout the world/server) but you can suggest a command, as in having the player click on 'click me' then it saying in chat the command you would suggest they use. maybe someday mojang will add forced chat messages in the chat box(I highly doubt it).